# Save complex numpy array as image using scikit-image

Tags: python, scikit-image, complextype

Get following error when try I to use io.imsave("image.jpg",array)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Fourer.py", line 37, in <module>
    io.imsave( "test.jpg", fImage2)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_io.py", line 131, in imsave
    if is_low_contrast(arr):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\exposure\exposure.py", line 503, in is_low_contrast
    dlimits = dtype_limits(image, clip_negative=False)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\dtype.py", line 49, in dtype_limits
    imin, imax = dtype_range[image.dtype.type]
KeyError: <class 'numpy.complex128'>
```

it's a 2n complex array I use

```
array = [[ 3.25000000e+02+0.00000000e+00j -1.25000000e+01+1.72047740e+01j
  -1.25000000e+01+4.06149620e+00j -1.25000000e+01-4.06149620e+00j
  -1.25000000e+01-1.72047740e+01j]
 [-6.25000000e+01+8.60238700e+01j -8.88178420e-16+8.88178420e-16j
   0.00000000e+00+1.29059879e-15j  0.00000000e+00+1.29059879e-15j
  -8.88178420e-16-8.88178420e-16j]
 [-6.25000000e+01+2.03074810e+01j -8.88178420e-16+4.44089210e-16j
  -3.55271368e-15+5.46706420e-15j -3.55271368e-15+5.46706420e-15j
  -8.88178420e-16-4.44089210e-16j]
 [-6.25000000e+01-2.03074810e+01j -8.88178420e-16+4.44089210e-16j
  -3.55271368e-15-5.46706420e-15j -3.55271368e-15-5.46706420e-15j
  -8.88178420e-16-4.44089210e-16j]
 [-6.25000000e+01-8.60238700e+01j -8.88178420e-16+8.88178420e-16j
   0.00000000e+00-1.29059879e-15j  0.00000000e+00-1.29059879e-15j
  -8.88178420e-16-8.88178420e-16j]]
```

How can i save i complex array as image?

Comment: I'd suggest using `np.save` instead, which uses NumPy's `.npy` format.

Answer (score 0):

If that matrix was obtained from the FFT of an image, then you first need to do Inverse FFT. Only then, you can save it using io.imsave.
If that is the case, take a look at skimage's:

----> [Inverse Fourier Transform](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.4/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.ifft2)